# Open pull request on a single commit

Tags: git, github

I have a branch with 3 or 4 commits pushed to it on GitHub.  I would like to open a pull request to our master branch involving only one of those commits.  However, the GitHub interface appears to require a new PR to include all those commits.

Is it possible to open a new pull request using a subset of my branch's commits?

Answer (score 3):

It would be best to create a branch just to encompass that pull request. It sounds like one isolated feature or bug fix anyway. During the pull request, the maintainer of the repository might request changes. It is easier to incorporate those changes to the pull request if you limit your Git branch to only the changes necessary for the pull request.

Comment: To help with this OP you might be able to use `git stash` along with the commit hash to grab that one commit, open a new branch and `git stash apply` it.

Comment: Depending on how isolated each commit is, `git cherry-pick` is an option too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  Yes, absolutely a new branch would make sense but sometimes you neglect to do it/something slips through the cracks or you commit to the wrong branch (guilty.)

Comment: @jkj2000: That's where `git cherry-pick` comes in handy. You can "cherry pick" individual commits (just copy one commit to your current branch). You can also use `git checkout BRANCH_NAME -- path/to/file` and then edit the file from there.